# Salesforce use and edit apps

Tags: servicecloud

my organization is using the standard Sales Cloud product.
Now the idea came up to enhance it by adding a support ticket tool (like [TeamSupport](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001rIQNEA2)).
Furthermore we're seeking for a solution to also integrate our entitlement management into salesforce. But it seems there's no application which matches our needs.

Question: Under the assumption we inegrate such a support ticket tool, is it possible to edit it programatically afterwards? So to speak: we get the tool and add the needed features by our own?

Is this possible at all, or are these "apps" not editable?
If that's not possible, any suggestions?

You may notice I don'thave any knowledge about salesforce since I'm not using it at all.
So please explain like I'm 5 :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to investigate the [Salesforce Service Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/service-cloud/overview/).

This salesforce functionality is oriented at customer support and ticket/case management. It comes with functionality for **entitlements**, **email to ticket** integration, **call center** integration possibilities, **multi-channel** customer interaction, **knowledge base** (both internal and external), and more features that you may find useful.

If it's not included in your current salesforce org, it can be added by salesforce under an additional contract. Your account manager should be able to give you specific details or even provide a demo. There's a ton of demo's on youtube if you look for salesforce service cloud or salesforce cases.

Update: if you're talking about adding appExchange apps to your salesforce org: In most cases they are not editable (managed packages).

Comment: I will put it on the list of considerable options. Thanks!